# Obtaining start position of istringstream token

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, istringstream

Is there a way to find the start position of tokens extracted by `istringstream::operator >>`?

For example, my current failed attempt at checking `tellg()` ([run online](https://ideone.com/o8bzO8)):

```
string test = "   first     \"  in \\\"quotes \"  last";
istringstream strm(test);

while (!strm.eof()) {

    string token;
    auto startpos = strm.tellg();
    strm >> quoted(token);
    auto endpos = strm.tellg();
    if (endpos == -1) endpos = test.length();

    cout << token << ": " << startpos << " " << endpos << endl;

}
```

So the output of the above program is:

```
first: 0 8
  in "quotes : 8 29
last: 29 35
```

The end positions are fine, but the start positions are the start of the whitespace leading up to the token. The output I *want* would be something like:

```
first: 3 8
  in "quotes : 13 29
last: 31 35
```

Here's the test string with positions for reference:

```
          1111111111222222222233333
01234567890123456789012345678901234  the end is -1

   first     "  in \"quotes "  last

        ^--------------------^-----^ the end positions i get and want
^-------^--------------------^------ the start positions i get
   ^---------^-----------------^---- the start positions i *want*
```

Is there any straightforward way to retrieve this information *when using an `istringstream`*?

Comment: Please clarify...  You have provided example output from your program, and then you've shown an example of the output you want to see, which is identical to the first example.

Comment: @paddy Ah, collateral damage from an edit. Thanks for spotting that. One moment.... Fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Second, you can use the [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) stream manipulator to swallow whitespace before reading the next `token` value, then `tellg()` will report the start positions you are looking for, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

...

string test = "   first     \"  in \\\"quotes \"  last";
istringstream strm(test);

while (strm >> ws) {

    string token;
    auto startpos = strm.tellg();
    if (!(strm >> quoted(token)) break;
    auto endpos = strm.tellg();
    if (endpos == -1) endpos = test.length();

    cout << token << ": " << startpos << " " << endpos << endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ZBqObV)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I figured it'd be an easy job. I'm just too burnt to figure it out.

Comment: @JasonC updated to handle that failure

Comment: I could've sworn there was a `>>` to grab the current position; that'd smooth it all out. I might be remembering some other language or maybe I'm thinking of `scanf`. One sec, let's see....

Comment: @JasonC [not that I see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). Maybe you are thinking of [`std::showpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpos)? But that is for an entirely different purpose. Yeah, `scanf()` has `%n`. Should not be difficult to create a custom stream manipulator to output the stream's current position, though.

Comment: [Bah](https://c.tenor.com/BFPaMElzoxkAAAAC/curse-aukerman.gif). Easy one to toss together though, I guess.

Comment: I've really enjoyed watching your last comment slowly evolve, btw. I remember when it was just a young "nope". Ah, nostalgia. 5 minutes ago... seems like only yesterday. Time sure does fly by.